# Como acessar o console de uma aplicação Elixir?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

Tenho um aplicativo com back-end em Elixir que está com um bug no servidor, de forma que novos usuários não conseguem fazer um novo cadastro no app, mas os usuários antigos conseguem utilizar normalmente.

Preciso inserir um novo usuário manualmente pelo console do Elixir para que esse novo usuário seja gravado no banco de dados e consiga utilizar o app, mas não tenho ideia de como posso fazer isso.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode rodar `iex -S mix` na raiz do projeto para abrir um [shell interativo do Elixir (IEx)](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html) com as dependências listadas no [Mix](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.html).

Dentro do shell você pode interagir com seu ORM. Se for o Ecto, por exemplo:

```
iex> {:ok, inserted} = MyApp.Repo.insert(%Post{title: "this is unique"})
```

Se você estiver usando Phoenix, vale usar também o comando `iex -S mix phx.server`, que além do shell interativo, também inicia o servidor Phoenix.

Se estiver usando Releases, acesse o shell com `bin/<release-name> remote`, que é útil em produção.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode abrir seu terminal/CMD a depender do O.S, acessa o diretório com o module responsável e use esse comando para acessar o console, exe: iex -S mix